# WSO2 DAS. Metadata and Rules management

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-cep

I implemented a CEP demo case using WSO2 DAS:
Several event sources, realtime analytics using SiddhiQL (with queries to external data sources and applying ML models from WSO2 ML), WSO2 Dashboard.

Everything works perfectly. Great solution!

But I could't find some important (for me) features:

1. Metadata management. My simple case consists more than 50 objects
   (streams, ex. plans, publishers, receivers). How can I manage and
   support objects in complex projects (> 500 obj)? There are no
   projects, tree views, libraries, object filtering,
   enabling/disabling, doc labels/boxes, etc. External metadata
   management tool, extensions? Any other idea?
2. Rules management. Rules library? GUI for creating rules for business
   users? Is it possible to integrate WSO2 CEP with BRMS Tool (e.g.
   JBoss Drools)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no out of box metadata management feature in the WSO2CEP/WSO2DAS but for complex projects you can maintain c-apps and deploy c-apps in the runtime. Please refer DAS documentation for more details [1]. You can make analytics artifacts as a project using WSO2 developer studio which is based on Eclipse [2]
2. Rules related DAS artifacts could be configured by using Template Manager. This UI is for business users. Technical users can define a template for a scenario by specifying configurable values. Then business users can give values for those. As an example in a siddhi query which is checking temprature is greater than 30 degree, the value 30 could make as configurable in the template. So those 30 value could be given from template manager UI. Likewise other artifacts like spark scripts, gadgets could make configurable with templates. For more details again refer documentation [3]. There is also a blog written  to explain this very briefly, you can refer that too [4], but please note that templates and configurations in the latest DAS310 is different from the blog post content

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Packaging+Artifacts+as+a+C-App+Archive

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Creating+an+Analytics+Project

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Managing+DAS+Artifacts+via+Template+Manager

[4] http://blog.tharik.org/2015/09/user-friendly-execution-management-with.html

Comment: I used all of your tips. It helps me!
Now I see the development process in this way: 
1) I develop a scenario on DEV instance of WSO2 DAS (because I can't see flow and errors in Dev Studio). Can I use several DAS instance on 1 machine?
2) I import all artifacts from Dev Studio project (1 project per logical set of artifacts in DAS) and export them into Carbon App file.
3) I import Carbon App file from DAS Production instance. 
Is it optimal development process?

Comment: Yes you can develop the capps on development studio and then import them in the DAS. You can have multiple DAS packs and run separately in a single machine by offsetting the port. https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Glossary#Glossary-Portoffset